# Is $\omega \ncong \omega+1$ but $\omega \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{1-1} \omega+1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am working my way through ordinal arithmetic and cardinality, so I wanted a quick reality check that I am correctly differentiating between structure preserving bijections (isomorphisms) and non-structure preserving bijections.

A consequence of this difference is the following statement:

> $\omega \ncong \omega+1$ but $\omega \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{1-1} \omega+1$, where $\omega$ refers to the set of all natural numbers

That is to say, there is no *structure-preserving* bijection between $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ (where the "structure" in question is $\in$ and its corresponding properties)...however $ \omega \approx \omega+1$ (i.e. there is a **non**-structure preserving bijection between $\omega$ and $\omega+1$).

Is this the right idea?

(There appears to be a similar post here: [$\omega+1\sim\omega$ but $\omega+1\not\simeq\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096371/omega1-sim-omega-but-omega1-not-simeq-omega) but I think the relationship $\sim$ defined by the author of the post presupposes that the individual is familiar with the **Schroder-Bernstein** theorem).

Comment: When you say $\omega$, do you specifically mean the first infinite ordinal?

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, this looks correct. However, it's important to keep in mind that there is ordinal addition and cardinal addition. For ordinal addition we have $1 + \omega = \omega$ and $\omega + 1 \neq \omega.$ For cardinal addition we have $1 + \omega = \omega + 1 = \omega.$ In each of these I'm interpreting $1$ and $\omega$ as both an ordinal number and as a cardinal number, which in formal treatments of set theory will automatically be true since cardinal numbers are (in formal set theory, and especially in axiomatic set theory) defined to be certain ordinal numbers.

Comment: @Arthur yes. The set of all natural numbers. I have made an edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. There can't be a structure-preserving isomorphism $\omega \to \omega + 1$. The latter has a maximal element $\omega$ but the former does not, so what $x$ could satisfy $f(x) = \omega$? Or rather, if we did have such an $x$, where would $x+1$ go?

But they are of the same cardinality, as you can easily see by taking the maximal element $\omega$ from $\omega + 1$ and shoving it at the beginning. That particular bijection doesn't preserve the order structure, but it is a bijection.